# Flutter novice with no clue on how can I build a ListView, for example, of doctors depending on the specialty from previous list?

Tags: listview, flutter, push, builder

I have a list of medical specialties displayed in a ListView, I want to be able to click on a specialty then display a listview with the doctors with that specialty. If I click on "Cardiologist" to show the doctors cardiologists. I can't get it to work. I have the  Specialty class, the Doctors class, Doctors' List and Specialties List. I have messed up my code so much that I can't even post it here. Can you please show me how to display the "Specialties's List" and click on a specialty to then navigate and construct the "Doctors' List" matching the selected specialties? Thanks a lot!!!

Here the classes and lists:

```
class Doctors {
  String name;
  String specialty;

  Doctors({
    this.name,
    this.specialty,
  });
}

List<Doctors> dummyDoctors = [
  Doctors(
    name: "Susan Finn",
    specialty: "Surgery",
  ),
  Doctors(
    name: "Mike Donovan",
    specialty: "Cardiology",
  ),
  Doctors(
    name: "Tom Sharp",
    specialty: "Dermatology",
  ),
];

class Specialties{
  final String specialty;

  Specialties({
    this.specialty
    });
}

List<Specialties> specialties = [
  Specialties(
    specialty: 'Surgery',
  ),
  Specialties(
    specialty: 'Cardiology',
  ),
  Specialties(
    specialty: 'Dermatology',
  ),
];
```

This is what I have all mess up and need to know / understand, this  :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:training2/specialty_modelo.dart';
import 'package:training2/second_screen.dart';

class SpecialtyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String get specialty => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 300.0,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: specialties.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              Specialties specialties = specialties[index];
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => SecondRoute(
                      specialties: specialties)),),
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  width: 210.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            specialty,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Zvi Karp suggested this for the second screen where doctors are to be displayed according to the speciality, still no luck, can't get it to work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:training2/specialty_modelo.dart';

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  //final specialtyDoctorsList allDoctors;

    SecondRoute({
        this.specialty, Specialties specialties,
    });
    final String specialty;

  get allDoctors => null;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Doctors> specialtyDoctorsList = allDoctors.where((Doctors doctor) => doctor.specialty == this.specialty);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting stuck? this might help to get started https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Comment: I can go back and forth, but my second screen shows all the doctors.

Comment: ok, great, i have posted an answer, hope i helped!

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments, in the first page call the second page and pass it the selected specialty like so:

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute(specialty: specialty)),
            );
```

then in the second page get the specialty as an argument:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
    SecondRoute({
        this.specialty,
    });
    final String specialty;
```

Now you can use it to get specific doctors:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Doctors> specialtyDoctorsList = allDoctors.where((Doctors doctor) => doctor.specialty == this.specialty);
    return Container();
  }
```

Comment: Zvi Karp, thanks, but since I couldn't get it to work I have edited my original post and included all the files (model class, first screen and second screen), still can't get it to work (can't figure it out :-( Thanks a lot for your help